# Deleting records in adotable with certain criteria

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i have tried looking online but had no luck,
How i could delete all records in an adotable  in button click, which  match a varying criteria. For example i want to be able to delete all records in an  adotable where Labour_ID (this is a field name within the adotable) is equal to DBedit.Text.

sorry this is a bit vague, but suggestions would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can delete the rows with a simple loop:

```
while ADOTable1.Locate('Labour_ID', Edit1.Text, []) do
  ADOTable1.Delete;
```

Better yet is to use a TADOQuery instead, and do it with SQL:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE Labour_ID = :Labour_ID';
ADOQuery1.Params.ParamByName('Labour_ID').AsString := Edit1.Text;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

See the Delphi documentation on [TDataSet.Locate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet.Locate) for info on the last `LocateOptions` parameter. (The link is to XE2's docs, but it hasn't changed much (if at all) for ADO since D7).